# GVIZ: Custom label for continous axis(datetime)

Tags: google-visualization

I have a line chart where we plot some numbers against a `datetime` value on x-axis. Since, using `datetime` value on column type renders it a `continuous axis`, the column labels are auto generated.

We get only the time component as the column labels but not the date. Is there anything I can do to get the entire date time as the label?

(NOTE: I do not want to change the data type to string as I do not want even spacing in data points.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need to look at [formatters](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dateformatter) which use a subset of the [ICU SimpleDateFormat](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#_details).

Here is an example of how they work:

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addRows([
    [new Date(2012,1,5)],
    [new Date(2012,2,10)],
    [new Date(2012,3,15)],
    [new Date(2012,4,20)]
  ]);

  alert(data.getFormattedValue(3,0));

  var formatter1 = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'yyyy, MMM'});

  formatter1.format(data,0);

  alert(data.getFormattedValue(3,0));
}
```

Adjust to fit your data and needs, and presto! You have it working.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I also found that using the ICU pattern set with the hAxis.format option also gives the desired result.